# Importing date styles from .csv into Postgres table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TB
(
    .......
    ADMIT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    ......
);
```

with `ADMIT_DATE` as my date column. I want to import a dataset from a csv file which contains dates of ADMIT_DATE table in this form "10032006" i.e. 10 March 2006. When I try loading the csv into table using this

```
COPY testing.TB(..., ADMIT_DATE, ...) 
FROM '\filename.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get an error and suggests to use different datestyle:

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "10232006"
> HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I tried using this but didn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE TB
(
    ... 
    ADMIT_DATE DATE "DDMMYYY"
    ... 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where you're dealing with non-standard formats it's best to first import the file to a staging table (e.g., with all or just the non-importable columns set up to be type `text`) and move the data to the final table or modify the staging table in-place, applying necessary transformations in the process.

In your case, you need to run the `ADMIT_DATE` column through a [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) or simply `to_date()` function, both of which let you define a mask instructing the db how to interpret the text representation: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4BvkA0vg)

```sql
CREATE TABLE testing.staging_tb(... text, ADMIT_DATE text, ... text);

COPY testing.staging_tb(..., ADMIT_DATE, ...) 
    FROM '\filename.csv' 
    DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

ALTER TABLE testing.staging_tb
    ALTER COLUMN ADMIT_DATE
    TYPE date
    USING (to_timestamp(ADMIT_DATE,'DDMMYYYY'));
```

If you can't afford to have more than 2 copies of the file, one in the original location and one in the database, you can resort to [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) and apply your changes in a `select` from that.